# How to fix the margin on the right of the row 'two' class?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website layout using HTML5 & CSS3.

I've tried setting the margin to zero. Also have set the border to zero, still it won't work. Is there any method for width like that exist for height(100vh). Anything like that would also help

```css
.row {
  zoom: 1;
  /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

.two {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-right: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row two">
  <h2>Here’s how Babbel gets you conversational fast!</h2>
</div>
```

The blue background is expected to  cover the full width of the window.

Comment: There is a thing like `vh` for width it is: `vw`. Anyways you don't need it in your example. Block elements spread to full width of their parent containers by default [see your demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/hyf86qbn/1/). You really don't need to support IE 6 or 7, 8, 9 and 10 [since these browsers are out of support by their vendor.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-ie-support)

Comment: @Nico O It's still not working. Should i paste the entire code.

Comment: You should post (just) the code necessary to reproduce your problem along with a description of the desired result.

Comment: `body` has a margin by default; set that to 0. if that's not the issue, post a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: @Mr Lister I Can't find an option to post a screenshot. I've uploaded this onto my github account.If its okay, here is the link https://github.com/sterben04/languages.

Answer (score 1):

### Using `body{margin: 0;}` and `box-sizing: border-box;`

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  zoom: 1;
  /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

.two {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 0;
/*   margin-right: -100px; */
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="row two">
  <h2>Here’s how Babbel gets you conversational fast!</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Body has a default margin. If you reset that to zero, you will achieve the box's spreading side to side. See below

```css
body{
  margin:0
}

.row {
  zoom: 1;
  /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}

.two {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-right: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row two">
  <h2>Here’s how Babbel gets you conversational fast!</h2>
</div>
```